# Chrome console: "Refused to autofill iframe with different origin"

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, twitter, same-origin-policy

I'm getting the above error in the Chrome (but not FF) JS console. It seems to be related to the Twitter widgets (the standard "Tweet" and "Follow @username" buttons), because it goes away when I comment them out.

The widget markup is just a `<a>`, and gets turned into an iframe by a process I don't fully understand, especially since the error persists when I comment out the Twitter JS that presumably makes this happen.

Error in full:

```
Refused to autofill iframe with different origin   onloadwff.js:78
  console_error                                    onloadwff.js:78
  fillfield                                        onloadwff.js:183
  receiveBG                                        onloadwff.js:125
  EventImpl.dispatchToListener                     extensions::event_bindings:397
  publicClass.(anonymous function)                 extensions::utils:89
  EventImpl.dispatch_                              extensions::event_bindings:379
  EventImpl.dispatch                               extensions::event_bindings:403
  publicClass.(anonymous function)                 extensions::utils:89
  dispatchOnMessage                                extensions::messaging:304
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error in chrome  36.0.1985.125 on Ubuntu, (but not FF) and I have got no code at all related to Twitter on my page - although there are Facebook references. The complete error looks identical to yours. It only started a couple of days ago I think...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The LastPass extension was causing this for me.  Temporarily disabled, and the errors went away.

Comment: Worked for me too. Annoying though. (The errors come back once you reenable it, in case anyone is wondering.) Thanks!